# MySQL custom ordering 

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores user login ID. Now i want to display information so tat the logged in user's ID should be on top and other should be at the bottom. For exapmle if the user ID is 3 then all the records with 3 should appear first and other records should follow the list.. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN user_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
...
```